# does "wide range of food" mean? please give me an alternative if it does not

Tags: word-usage, word-request

In the following sentence. is "wider range of food" a good collocation? I mean the range of things that an animals consumes as food. Is there any specific word to mention this?

> During the drought, however, omnivores appear to suffer less because
> they have a **wider range of food** compared with carnivorous or
> herbivorous species.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *have* in "they have a wider range of food" could either mean *eat* or *possess* as in "have got" that being the case both meanings are appropriate.
The sentence could be rephrased as:

1. ...appear to suffer less because they can eat a **greater variety** of food than that of carnivores and herbivores."
2. ... because they **consume a wider range of food compared to**...

Answer (score 0):

"Wide range of food" is okay, but the animals *eat* a wide range of food (not *have*).

The word meaning "the range of food" is the animals **diet** so you might say that "omnivores have a more diverse diet..."

Comment: Both "have" and "eat" work fine here.  If I have dinner, it means I eat dinner.  If I have a wide range of food, I eat a wide range of food.

Comment: "Have" is the weak choice. If you "have" food this might mean you possess it.  "Eat" is a much better choice of word in this context

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it.